# Conditions on the velocity ensuring that a flow moves points along the boundary of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control, flows, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let

- $\tau>0$;
- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be Lipschitz continuous in the second argument uniformly with respect to the first with $v(\;\cdot\;,x)\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$;
- $X^{s,\:x}$ denote the unique element of $C^0([s,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ with $$X^{s,\:x}(t)=x+\int_s^tv(r,X^{s,\:x}(r))\:{\rm d}r\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau]\tag1$$ for $(s,x)\in[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d$ and $$T_t(x):=X^x(t):=X^{0,\:x}(t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$.

Now let $M$ be a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $\partial M$ denote the manifold boundary of $M$.

> I would like to know which assumption on $v$ we need to impose in order to ensure that $$T_t(\partial M)=\partial M\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag2.$$

Phrased differently, I want to find a condition on $v$ ensuring that $T_t$ moves a "particle" $x$ "along the boundary" $\partial M$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$:

[image]

I've read that we need to assume that $$\langle\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial M},\nu_{\partial M}\rangle=0\tag3,$$ where $\nu_{\partial M}$ denotes the unique outer unit normal field on $\partial M$. However, I don't see why $(3)$ implies the $(2)$. And is $(3)$ an additional assumption at all? It seems like $(3)$ should always hold: Let $(s,x)\in[0,\tau]\times\partial M$. The claim $\langle v(s,x),\nu_{\partial M}(x)\rangle=0$ is equivalent to $v(s,x)\in T_x\:\partial M$, where $T_x\:\partial M$ denotes the tangent space of $\partial M$ at $x$. Now, if $$\gamma(h):=X^{s,\:x}(s+h)\;\;\;\text{for }h\in[0,\tau-s],$$ then $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=v(s,x)$. Thus, $v(s,x)\in T_x\:\partial M$. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is $E$ supposed to be?

Comment: Do you see why its true when M is a disk in a plane? Does your 'proof' given at end of your question hold in this case?

Comment: @JackLee Sorry, I'm used to consider flows on a Banach space $E$. Here $E=\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Please clarify: Do you mean that $(3)$ doesn't hold if $E=\mathbb R^2$ and $M=\{x\in\mathbb R^2:\left\|x\right\|\le1\}$?

Comment: And $\Omega=M$ I suppose? You'd make it a lot easier for those of who try to answer your questions if you'd proofread them before posting them, and make sure all of your notations are consistent and well defined.

Comment: No, I meant your proof claiming that (3) is trivially satisfied. Lets take $v$ to be a constant vector field pointing in horizontal direction, parallel to x axis. Clearly (3) doesn't hold for most points on boundary of $M$.

Comment: @JackLee Yes, sorry. Fixed that now.

Comment: @PiyushGrover If $v$ is a constant, the wholse disk would be moved in that direction. So, I guess you're right, but where is the mistake in my proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the situation you described, if $M$ is properly embedded (i.e., topologically embedded and closed), the flow of a vector field takes $\partial M$ to itself if and only if the vector field is everywhere tangent to the boundary. For a proof of the "if" direction, see Lemma 9.33 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. (That lemma shows that the flow takes $M$ to itself if the vector field is everywhere tangent to the boundary, but if you look closely at the proof, it also shows that the flow preserves $\partial M$.)

The condition that $v$ is tangent to the boundary at a point $x\in \partial M$ is equivalent to the condition that $v$ is orthogonal to the unit normal vector there. (This is essentially the definition of a normal vector.)

If $M$ is not closed, the result is not true. For example, consider the case in which $M$ is the closed unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with one boundary point removed, and $v$ is a vector field that generates rotations. Then there is no nonzero time such that $T_t(\partial M)\subset\partial M$.

**To answer the question in your comment:** Once we know that $T_t(\partial M)\subset \partial M$ for each $t$, here's how to show that in fact equality holds.

First suppose $\partial M$ is connected. Because $T_t$ is a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ to itself and $\partial M$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$, it follows that $T_t(\partial M)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$ and therefore also (relatively) closed in $\partial M$.  On the other hand, since $T_t$ restricts to a diffeomorphism from $\partial M$ to itself, $T_t|_{\partial M}$ is an open map (as a map between $(d-1)$-dimensional manifolds), and therefore $T_t(\partial M)$ is (relatively) open in $\partial M$. By connectivity, therefore $T_t(\partial M) = \partial M$.

If $\partial M$ is not connected, just apply the argument above to each connected component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the "if-direction": Is your suggestion to consider $$\mathcal T:=\{t\in[0,\tau]:X^x(t)\in\partial M\}$$ for some fixed $x\in\partial M$ and prove that this set is equal to $[0,\tau]$? You're doing this by showing that it is closed and open, but you've assumed that $D$ is a regular domain of a smooth manifold. Here $D=\partial M$, but $\partial M$ is not topologically closed (hence not "properly embedded") in $\mathbb R^d$ or am I missing something? ($\partial M$ is closed in $M$ though, if that's relevant)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You're right -- for this to be true, you have to add the hypothesis that $M$ is properly embedded. I'll edit my response.

Comment: Meanwhile, [I've figured out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813950/47771) how we can prove that $T_t(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ as long as $\partial M$ is closed. However, why can we infer from this result that it's not only "$\subseteq$", but "$=$"?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: See my addition above.

Comment: Can we infer from $T_t(\partial\Omega)=\partial\Omega$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ that $T_t(\Omega)=\Omega$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$?

Comment: I'd still be interested in the question from my last comment.

Comment: What's $\Omega$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm always confusing $\Omega$ and $M$. So, $\Omega$ should be $M$. BTW, if we are able to show that $T_t(∂ M)\subseteq\partial M$ (as you did in your answer), aren't we able to use the same argumentation to hsow $T_t^{-1}(\partial M)\subseteq ∂M$? In the same manner, showing $T_t(M)\subseteq M$ and $T_t^{-1}(M)\subseteq M$ should be doable in the same way. All we would need to do is whowing that $T_t^{-1}$ solves a similar system as $(1)$. This is clearly the case when $v$ doesn't depend on time. I've asked for the general case here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3842350/47771.

Comment: A similar argument shows that $T_t(\text{Int}(M)) = \text{Int}(M)$, and therefore $T_t(M) = M$. You first show $T_t(M)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$ as above, and therefore  $T_t(\text{Int}(M)) = \text{Int}(M)\cap T_t(M)$ is relatively closed in $\text{Int}(M)$. And  $T_t(\text{Int}(M))$ is open because $T_t|_{\text{Int}(M)}$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: In your last comment, I think we first need to show that $T_t(\operatorname{Int}\:M)\subseteq\operatorname{Int}\:M$ for all $t$ (are you denoting the manifold interior or the topological interior by $\operatorname{Int}\:M$?). How do you infer this from $(3)$?

Comment: It's still not clear to me how you infer the invariance of the (manifold, I  guess) interior. Maybe I've misunderstood you, but if I got you right, you say that $(3)$ implies this. And it's actually intuitively plausible that $(3)$ ensures that a trajectory originating from the manifold cannot leave the boundary. Please take a look at the question I've asked for this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/372810/91890.