# Show that the manifold interior is invariant under this flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, flows

Let $\tau>0$, $d\in\mathbb N$, $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be continuous in the first argument with $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left\|v(t,x)-v(t,y)\right\|\le c\left\|x-y\right\|\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb R^d$$ for some $c\ge0$, $X^x\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ denote the unique solution of $$X^x(t)=x+\int_0^tv(s,X^x(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag2$$ for $x\in\mathbb R^d$, $$T_t(x):=X^x(t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

Assuming that $$v(t,x)\in T_x\:\partial M\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\tau]\times\partial M\tag3,$$ [I was able to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813950/47771) that $$\forall x\in\partial M:\exists\delta\in(0,\tau]:\forall t\in[0,\delta):T_t(x)\in\partial M.\tag4$$ Moreover, if $\partial M$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$, then $$T_t(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau].\tag5$$

> Are we able to give a condition similar to $(3)$ (and closedness of $\partial M$ in $\mathbb R^d$) to show analogue results hold for $M^\circ$?

Let's try to repeat the proof for $\partial M$. For the moment, we are assuming nothing else than that $M$ is any $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $M$, $\phi$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism of $\Omega$ onto an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times[0,\infty)$ and $x\in\Omega^\circ$. We want to show that there is a $\delta\in(0,\tau]$ such that $$T_t(x)\in\Omega^\circ\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\delta)\tag6.$$ We know that $\Omega^\circ$ itself is a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ (without boundary), $\tilde\phi:=\left.\phi\right|_{\Omega^\circ}$ is a chart for $\Omega^\circ$ and $\tilde U:=\tilde\phi(\Omega^\circ)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^k$. Let $\tilde u:=\tilde\phi(x)$. The map $$h(t,\tilde u):=T_{\tilde\phi^{-1}(\tilde u)}(\tilde\phi)v(t,\tilde\phi^{-1}(u))\;\;\;\text{for }(t,u)\in[0,\tau]\times\tilde U$$ is continuous so that we know that there is a $\delta\in(0,\tau]$ and a $Y\in C^1([0,\delta),\tilde U)$ with $$Y(t)=\tilde u+\int_0^th(s,Y(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\delta)\tag6.$$ Let $Z:=\tilde\phi^{-1}\circ Y$. By definition, $$Z(0)=x\tag7.$$ Moreover, $${\rm D}\tilde\phi^{-1}(Y(t))=T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)^{-1}\tag8$$ and $$Y'(t)=T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)v(t,Z(t))\tag9$$ for all $t\in[0,\delta)$ and hence $$Z'(t)=\underbrace{{T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)}^{-1}T_{Z(t)}(\tilde\phi)}_{=\:\operatorname{id}_{T_x\:\Omega^\circ}}v(t,\underbrace{Z(t)}_{\in\:\Omega^\circ})\tag{10}.$$

> Clearly, the goal is to infer that $$Z=\left.X^x\right|_{[0,\:\delta)}\tag{11},$$ from which we could conclude, since, by construction, $$Z([0,\delta))\subseteq\Omega^\circ\tag{12}.$$
>
> **Question 1**: However, the first problem with $(10)$ is that - without any further assumption - $$v(t,\underbrace{Z(t)}_{\in\:\Omega^\circ})\in T_x\:\Omega^\circ\tag{13}$$ does **not** hold. What do we need to assume in order to ensure that? Does $(3)$ possibly imply $(13)$? <s>A sufficient assumption would clearly be $k=d$, since then we should have $T_x\:\Omega^\circ=\mathbb R^k$.</s> But is there a weaker assumption?
>
> **Question 2**: And what do we need to assume in order to conclude $$T_t(\Omega^\circ)\subseteq\Omega^\circ\tag{14}$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$?

### **EDIT**

Maybe we need to adjust our assumptions. We should have the following result: If $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is open and$^1$ $$\operatorname{Bd}U\subseteq T_t(\operatorname{Bd}U)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau],\tag{15}$$ then $$T_t(U)\subseteq U\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau].\tag{16}$$ In fact, assume $U$ is open, $x\in U$ and $$I:=\{t\in[0,\tau]:X^x(t)\not\in U\}\ne\emptyset.$$ Since $X^x(0)=x\in U$, $$\sigma:=\inf I\in I$$ and $$y:=X^x(\sigma)\in\operatorname{Bd}U\tag{18}.$$ Thus, by $(15)$, $$\tilde x:=T_\sigma^{-1}\in\operatorname{Bd}U\tag{19}.$$ By construction $$T_\sigma(\tilde x)=y=T_\sigma(x)\tag{20}.$$ And since $U$ is open, $U\cap\operatorname{Bd}U=\emptyset$, which shows that $x\ne\tilde x$ and hence that $T_\sigma$ is not injective. Since $T_\sigma$ is a bijection, this is a contradiciton and hence $I=\emptyset$.

> As long as $\partial M$ coincides with the topological boundary $\operatorname{Bd}M$ (for example, if $M$ is $d$-dimensional and properly embedded), [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3851369/47771) shows that $(5)$ already implies $$T_t(\operatorname{Bd}M)=\operatorname{Bd}M\tag{21}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau].$$ But, as long as I'm not missing anything, $\operatorname{Bd}M^\circ\ne\operatorname{Int}M$. So, we cannot apply the former result. Can we fix this?

---

$^1$ I'm denoting the topological boundary (interior) by $\operatorname{Bd}U$ ($\operatorname{Int}M$) in order to distinguish it from the manifold boundary (interior) $\partial U$ ($U^\circ$).

Comment: I think the condition you need is simply $\langle v(t,x),n(x)\rangle < 0, \forall x\in\partial M$, where $n(x)$ is the outer normal, assuming the boundary is smooth.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Regarding your 1st comment: Are you asking this or are you hinting me to the counterexample you've provided? Anyways, what I got in mind was $T_x\:\Omega=\mathbb R^k$; not $T_x\:\Omega^\circ=\mathbb R^k$. So, I've striked out this part.

Comment: @PiyushGrover I'm not sure what your notation means either. However, what I wrote about $k=d$ was that I thought it would imply $T_x\:\Omega^\circ=\mathbb R^k$ (but it only implies $T_x\:\Omega=\mathbb R^k$; I guess $T_x\:\Omega^\circ=(\mathbb H^k)^\circ$ is the correct identity), in which case $(13)$ would trivially be satisfied.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Regarding your 2nd comment: I guess what you've got in mind is that whenever $x\in\partial M$, $v\in T_x\:M$ and $h:=T_x(\phi)v$, then $v$ is either inward pointing (which is the case iff $h\in(\mathbb H^k)^\circ$), outward pointing (which is the case iff $h\not\in\mathbb H^k$) or $v\in T_x\:\partial M$ (which is the case iff $h\in\partial\mathbb H^k$). However, a [comment by Jack Lee](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370453/91890) seems to indicate that the desired claim holds without the assumption you've suggested or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually you may be right. The assumption can be removed since we are only concerned with finite-time invariance. No traj. from interior can escape to boundary in finite time, since that will violate backward-time uniqueness of the ODE, since the boundary is invariant.

Comment: I don't have a rigorous proof, but believe the above argument can be made rigorous without much pain.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Please take note of my edit.

Comment: @Linas I don't understand your comment. The tangent space $T_x\:\partial M$ is a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^d$. So, $v(t,x)\in T_x\:\partial M$ does not conflict with $v(t,x)\in\mathbb R^d$ at al.

Comment: @Linas Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. If $v$ is a function from $A\times B$ to $C$, then $v(a,b)$ is an element of $C$. The same applies here, with $A=[0,\tau]$ and $B=C=\mathbb R^d$. And nothing what I wrote implies or requires that $v$ is linear in the second argument.

Comment: Quite right. I completely misread what you wrote. When I first read it, I'd accidentally curryied your functions, and so I was mentally envisioning  $v(a)\in \mathbb{R^d}\times\mathbb{R}^d$ when I now see that you clearly wrote $v(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ .. blame it on being cross-eyed late at night. I will now delete my earlier comments to avoid further confusion.